# .net core file .exe is locked on server and could not be deleted

Tags: iis, deployment, .net-core

I Deployed a .net core 2.1 application on server with iis as a self contained application.

When i try delete all the files for deploy another version of this application, all files are deleted, except wwwroot folder and .exe file.

Both are delete but back to appear in the folder again.

I' ve tryied stop the application and pool application on iis but it not work, and this files appear over and over again.

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following.

1. look for the **<.exe>** file you are trying to delete in the task
   manager. if its there stop it and then try deleting your files.
2. Look for **dotnet.exe** in task manager, if it is there, stop it,
   and then try to delete

For me it was dotnet.exe that was causing the issue, and I had it resolved by stopping it

Answer (score 0):

Process monitor is a tool to monitor real-time file system.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

It will tell you who is read/write these files.

I believe it will help you figure out who is locking this. Then you only have to stop related process and try todelete these files again.